# Call the dynamically create linkbutton method of user controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a user control where I am creating the link button dynamically like this:

```
public void LoadShipmentDate(int shipmentDatemaxCount)
    {
        PlaceHolderShipmentDate.Controls.Clear();
        foreach(Control item in PlaceHolderShipmentDate.Controls.OfType<LinkButton>().ToList())
        {
            PlaceHolderShipmentDate.Controls.Remove(item);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < shipmentDatemaxCount; i++)
        {
            LinkButton excel_linkbutton = new LinkButton();
            excel_linkbutton.ID = "excel_linkbutton_" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString();
            excel_linkbutton.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString();
            excel_linkbutton.CommandArgument = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString();
            excel_linkbutton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(generate_excel_click);

            Panel panelshipmentNotificationsItem = new Panel();
            panelshipmentNotificationsItem.Controls.Add(excel_linkbutton);
            LiteralControl(shipmentDate));
            PlaceHolderShipmentDate.Controls.Add(panelshipmentNotificationsItem);
        }
    }

public void generate_excel_click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
  {
      //do something here
  }
```

Now, I am not able to call the generate_excel_clcik method when the link button is clicked. Everytime I clicked the Linkbutton the Page_load of aspx.page where this user control is registered get called but it did not call generate_excel_clcik method. How to call this method and also pass some params to this method?

Comment: It is calling postback thats what button click do unless you have update panel. What you are doing in generate_excel_click method? It is empty by now.